# How to find the default Java 1.4.2 heap size in AIX

Tags: java, aix, heap-memory

Hi can help to advise me how to find the default heap size ?

I didn't mention the minimum and maximum heap size in the startup script . However both max and minimum value auto set to 512 MB .

so where it is mentioned ?

I've tried the below command :

> Java -XX:PrintFlagFinal -version | grep HeapSize

but hitting below error

The JVM option is invalid: -XX:PrintFlagFinal
Could not create the java virtual machine.

> java -verbose:sizes -version

[JVMCI129 : unrecognized verbose option : -verbose:sizes]

[JVMCI123:unable to parse 1.2 format supplied options -rc=-6]

Could not create the Java virtual machine

Server : AIX
Java version : 1.4.2
Physical memory of our server is 23616MB

Comment: 1.4.2? Seriously? IBM is your vendor, ask them!

Answer (score 0):

Following command might help you

```
java -verbose:sizes -version
```

Comment: I have tried this but not working , I have edited my question to include his command